# PHP - Dropdown dynamic list with files

Tags: php

This is the situation: i have 4 folders, and inside each a bunch of files.

I am working on files operations in Php.
I would like, to create a dynamic form where, once is selected the folder, to fill up another dropdown list with the list of the files that are inside that folder.

This is the first part of the form, where the user can choose a folder:

```
<select name="origin">
    <option value="folder">Folder</option>
    <option value="folder2">Folder2</option>
    <option value="folder3">Folder3</option>
    <option value="folder4">Folder4</option>
</select>
```

How can i create the other dropdown list?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try using ajax to get the new results

Answer (score 2):

You need two things:

1. PHP file which will output the list of files
2. jQuery code to show the result using AJAX

Try this one and feel free to ask me for explanation:

1. PHP Code: name it

listfiles.php

```
$dir = $_GET["dir"];

$files = scandir($dir);

// Prepare the select box to echo
echo "<select name=\"files\">";

foreach ($files as $file)
{
// Return files only
if ( is_file($dir. $file) )
echo "<option value=\"$file\">$file</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
```

1. jQuery code could be used in any file, just create a new html or php file with this code:

listfiles.html

```
<select id="folder" name="origin">
<option value="C:\">C:\</option>
<option value="D:\">D:\</option>
</select>

<div id="files"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    //Bind a change event to the folder selector
    $("#folder").change(function()
    {
        var dir = $(this).val();

        $.get("listfiles.php", {"dir":dir}, function(response){
            //Show the files
            $("#files").html(response);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

For the script to work, FULL and valid folder names should be provided in the select box for folders.

Comment: Thank you for the reply first of all.
Is not working properly on my machine.
I have just to copy that code, modifying the folders in the select box, and should work no?

Comment: @johnnyfittizio the php file gets the directory path from the <select> with id "folder" so if this path doesn't exist, you will not get files for sure. Also make sure jQuery is included in whatever file you are using the second code in. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I modify this line:

<script type="text/javascript"  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">

The folders exist. 
It appear the first select with the 4 folders, but doesn't appear the second select.

The id of the form i have to leave 'folder' or i have to change it?

Comment: @johnnyfittizio you have to leave the id names intact if you are not sure about editing them. are you sure the folder names and values in the select appear in full path linke this "c:\folder3" ?

Comment: One more thing, the HTML file you are using must be called from webserver path not from the file path. For example you call http://localhost/listfiles.html not just open the file in browser and test it, this will not work. Better to rename the file listfiles.html to listfiles_test.php or anything .php and test it. If this doesn't work, can you call listfiles.php?dir=YOUR_FOLDER_PATH and tell me the result you get?

Comment: Yes, for the localhost there are no problem. Probably there is an issue reading the folders.
they are inside the root folder where i am working.
This is wrong?
They should be into C:\  ?

Comment: You can have them in any place as long as you set the value of the select to the FULL valid path to the folder like this: d:\some folder\ just try calling the php file, if it returns the result correctly, then the issue would be in you html code. Let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery (or just regular javascript if you wish) you can bind a function to the change event on the dropdown. Then call a file on the server using AJAX and return a JSON formatted string containing all the files and creating a dropdown from that. To get all files you can use the PHP function [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php).

Answer (score 0):

This process will require four steps:

1. Submit the folder name to a PHP script via AJAX when a value is selected.
2. Scan the directory for files and return the list as a JSON response
3. Create a new `<select>` via Javascript.
4. Read the response via Javascript and generate a new `<option>` elements for each item in the response.