# php-html populate a select list based on another select list

Tags: php, html, ajax, selectlist

Here's my query:
I have php page and a js page. I'm using datatables to display data. I have some select lists on top of the page to filter the data displayed in datatable. I have two filters called project and item. my requirement here is when I change project filter, item filter should get automatically changed. I'll query a oracle table using the value selected in project filter and retrieve all possible items. I want to populate item filter with these values. I know we can use ajax to do this, but I don't want to create a new php document to write the php-oracle query code. Can I use the main php document(php_self) to write the ajax query? 
My datatable:

```
    oTable = $('#dataTableView').dataTable({
        "aaSorting": [ [0,'asc'] ],
        "aoColumns" : dataTableColumns,
        "sScrollY": scrollVar, 
        "sScrollX": "100%", 
        "bScrollCollapse": true,    //to keep the header intact 
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": 'Show <select>'+
                '<option value="10">10<\/option>'+
                '<option value="25">25<\/option>'+
                '<option value="50">50<\/option>'+
                '<option value="100">100<\/option>'+
                '<option value="-1">All<\/option>'+
                '<\/select> records'
        },
        "iDisplayLength": -1,
        "sDom": '<"clear">lfrtipTS',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "css/TableTools-2.1.4/media/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
            "aButtons" : [ "xls", "print" ]
         }, 
    });
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Well you should use a file to query the db and output the result of course with the help of ajax. Here is a [previous example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17212488/2496219).